# How can I identify the client or caller of an EJB within the request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I have a system where several (20 or so) web app servers (hosting a website) talk to the same 2 - 4 EJB servers (through a VIP).  I'd like to know if it is possible to identify which one of those app servers generated a specific request.

For example: Website example.com works by sending HTTP requests to any of 20 app servers to handle the request.  These servers are named (internally) `app01` through `app20`.  It is ensured that all requests with the same session ID will be routed to the same app server, thus enabling us to logically track all requests from a single user.  Some requests will need some extra data not available directly, for which there is an EJB (2.1) application on another cluster of 3 servers, named `ejb01` to `ejb03`.  Connections to the EJB servers are made through a VIP (`ejb00`), which routes the requests round-robin style to the three EJB serves.

Within the logging (we use Apache Log4J) of the EJB servers, it would be really nice if I could identify which of the 20 app servers a request originated from.  The alternative is checking the logs on each server separately - but I don't have a good way to `grep` through the logs on 20 different boxes.

My question is:  is this possible within Standard EJB?  I'd be willing to do something non-standard, if there was nothing else, but it's gotta be reliable and work on my system.  We use Weblogic 11g, both for the web-app and the EJB servers.

I've seen suggestions to pass the identity of the caller as a parameter, but that would mean an extra parameter for each of 20+ EJB methods, and that's rather unwieldy.

Any solutions, anyone?

Comment: I recommend that you look into [LogStash](http://logstash.net/).  You could install it on the same box as your Weblogic servers.  Hopefully Weblogic has a logger like Tomcat's AccessLogValve.  You could then logout each request that way.  To figure out WHO is making the request, you could set the 'user-agent' for each of the 20 app servers.

Comment: @hooknc: We recently started using Splunk, which does make looking through the logs somewhat easier (and each EJB call _is_ logged), but the timing of the logs could be off by seconds, and pairing the logs on the client/server side is quite tedious, but that's what I'm reduced to doing in the meantime.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard solution.  There was a proposal in [JSR 149](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=149), but it was withdrawn.  Adding an extra parameter to the remote methods is probably your best option.  If you're using RMI remote, you might be able to write an ORB interceptor to add a custom context on the client side, receive it on the server side, and set a thread local around the method invocation on the server.

WebSphere Application Server has a non-standard solution called [work areas](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/welc6tech_wa_dev.html), which does work for remote EJB.

I am not familiar with WebLogic, so I don't know if they have a similar solution.  Searching for similar terms finds a [WorkContextMap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/context.html) that looks similar, but I don't know if it works for remote EJB since all the examples I can find are for webservices.

Comment: I was afraid of that ;-( So I'll have to figure out how to connect the disjoint logs.  Oh, well.  I guess that means I can bill for those hours, too ;-)